# Change header style for expanded Panel of Accordion in React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, accordion, react-bootstrap

For the clicked and active/expanded panel I would like to change the css style. That's because I would like to toggle an image arrow that points up or down inside the header of the panel.

I'm able to get the eventKey of the open panel, but I'm not able to reach the DOM element with the *panel-heading* css class.

What do you suggest?

Thanks

Code below

```
<Accordion onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
  <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #1" eventKey="1">
    Ad vegan
  </Panel>
  <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #2" eventKey="2">
    Cliche docet
  </Panel>
</Accordion>
```

That becomes

```
    <div role="tablist" class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 role="presentation" class="panel-title"><a role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false">Collapsible Group Item #1</a></h4></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!-- react-text: 36 -->Ad vegan
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 role="presentation" class="panel-title"><a role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false">Collapsible Group Item #2</a></h4></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!-- react-text: 43 -->Cliche docet
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you've attempted to use to solve the problem to this point?

Comment: Hello Ben, I've added the code which is quite standard. How could I reach the _panel-heading_ div in order to add an _active_ css class? Thanks

Comment: In jQuery it would be simply
`$('.panel-heading').on('click', function () {
  $('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});`

Comment: Is that the React-Bootstrap Panel or did you write it yourself (or is it from somewhere else?)

Comment: It is the React-Bootstrap Accordion [link](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-accordion)

Answer (score 2):

The React Bootstrap Panel accepts a node to use as a header (per: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v0.20.1/src/Panel.js#L144 and http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-props), so you can pass in something with the appropriate onClick handler to it as a header, perhaps something like:

```
<Accordion onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
  <Panel header={<div onClick={() => {console.log('Clicked')}}>"Collapsible Group Item #1"</div} eventKey="1">
    Ad vegan
  </Panel>
  <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #2" eventKey="2">
    Cliche docet
  </Panel>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your code seems to trow an error. Anyways, using `<Accordion onSelect={this.handleSelect} >`, I'm already able to get the eventKey of the clicked panel (which is, as far as I understand, what you suggest), but then I'm not able to reach the div that has the css class to be set to _active_.

Comment: You're right I missed a bracket sorry (updated). And is the div you're looking for the one I added? From the code I linked to (the link which looks at the actual code) the Panel doesn't accept an onClick for the `<div className="panel-heading">`, so you'd have to either use something like what I gave you or write/find another package.

Comment: Also if you do want to be able to have that onClick dynamically add a class to the div it's on and aren't sure how to write that let me know and I can update it with an example of how to go about doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately the div I'm looking for is not the one associated to <Panel> but it is a child. Btw your corrected code still gives me problems [link](https://s18.postimg.io/t4mpr7c09/Schermata_2016_09_07_alle_14_53_11.png)

Comment: It seems there should be a .collapsed class that would solve the problem. Unfortunately I've just updated to 0.30.3 and no .collapsed class appears.

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar issue by building 2 react components: one to create the PanelGroup and another to create each Panel item within the group. Then in the Panel item component I wrote a custom handler for the toggle onClick event that set the 'expanded' property of the Panel to the component's state. By using the state of the custom component I was able to keep the state of each toggle icon separate.

Custom Panel Group Component:

```
import CustomPanelGroupItem from './CustomPanelGroupItem';
import React from 'react';
import PanelGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/PanelGroup';

class CustomPanelGroup extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <PanelGroup 
                accordion 
                id='custom-panel-group-accordion'
            >
                {
                    PanelGroupData.map((item, key) => {
                        return (
                            <CustomPanelGroupItem
                                eventKey={key}
                                customPanelGroupItem={item}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }                

            </ PanelGroup>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomPanelGroup;
```

Custom Panel Component:

```
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faAngleDown, faAngleRight } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import React from 'react';
import Panel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Panel';

class CustomPanelGroupItem extends React.Component {
    state = {
        expanded: false,
        toggleIcon: faAngleRight
    }

    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            expanded: !this.state.expanded,
            toggleIcon: this.state.expanded ? faAngleRight : faAngleDown
        });
    }

     render() {
        return (
            <Panel 
                eventKey={this.props.eventKey}
                expanded={this.state.expanded}
            >
                <Panel.Heading >
                    <Panel.Toggle 
                        componentClass='div'
                        onClick={this.handleToggle}
                    >
                        {/* Code here for the panel toggle */} 
                    </Panel.Toggle>                 
                </Panel.Heading>
                <Panel.Body collapsible>
                    {/* Code here for the panel body */}
                </Panel.Body>
            </Panel>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomPanelGroupItem;
```